# Items not aligning properly in vue

Tags: vue.js, layout, alignment, vuetify.js

I am using vue with vuetify library to create a page. On the page I have cards which can be of any numbers which I want to display. I am using a loop to display all cards. But the alignment is having an issue. All the cards are coming in one whole row. It is ok if the cards are just a few. The alignment looks fine then. But if the cards are more like around 10 the page looks off.

[image: Image of the layout]

```
<template>
<div class="d-flex justify-center mb-6 mt-10">

    <v-card
      class="mr-4 ml-4"
      v-for="(cat, index) in cards"
      :key="index"
      outlined
    >
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn @click="getdata(cat._id)" plain>
          {{ cat.category }}
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    
  </v-card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the class `flex-wrap` so that items continue in a new line rather than overflowing.

```html
// (...)
<div class="d-flex justify-center flex-wrap mb-6 mt-10">
// (...)
```

Comment: Nice that worked. But the items that are in the bottom now are sticked with the items at the top. There is no space in between them. @sebasaenz

Comment: You'll need to add a margin in that case

Comment: I have a margin of mt-10 but that is not applying to the items in the next line

Comment: Where are you adding the `mt-10` class?

Comment: Ok got it. It worked. Need to add the top margin to the card. Thanks